# Unexpected change in the value of variables when reading from file using fread

Tags: c, network-programming, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to write two network programs in C:

i. a client program that requests a file from a server, first sending information about the file to request via UDP and then opening a TCP socket which it will use to receive the requested file. (the client acts as a server on the TCP connection to receive the file.)

ii. a server program that will receive information about the requested file via UDP and the connect with the client via TCP to send the file.

I think something strange happens on the server when I try to read from the requested file using fread:
the value of the TCP socket file descriptor changes and the value of the stream pointer (FILE*) which I am trying to read from also changes. I've spent a bit of time looking at it but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I've tried to add some redundant variables (socket, file, original_fd) to store the affected values before the call to fread but those seem to also have changed after the call to fread (you can see this in the screenshots I post). I have not been able to find a post on S/O with a similar problem.
(I'm building and running the programs using Windows Subsystem for Linux.)

[image: server (left) and client (right) programs side by side]

the actual server program:

```
#include <sys/socket.h> /*  socket definitions        */
#include <sys/types.h>  /*  socket types              */
#include <arpa/inet.h>  /*  inet (3) funtions         */
#include <unistd.h>         /*  misc. UNIX functions      */
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "helpers.h"

/*  Global constants  */
#define LISTENQ 1024
#define DEFAULT_UDP_PORT 2002
#define MAX_LINE 1000
#define FILE_REQUEST_SIGNAL_SIZE_BYTES (MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH + 5)
#define RECEIVE_SIGNAL_FLAGS 0x0
#define SEND_SIGNAL_FLAGS 0x0

void parse_cmd_line_arguments(int, char* [], short int*);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  // INET ADDRESS VARIABLES
  int udp_socket;                                                           // the server's udp socket
    int tcp_socket;                                                         // the server's tcp socket (will only be instantiated on file request)
    short int udp_port;                                                 // the server's (udp) port number
    struct sockaddr_in server_address;                          // the address of the server
    struct sockaddr_in client_address;                          // the address of the client (ip address and port)
    socklen_t client_address_length = sizeof(client_address); // length of the client's address struct
  socklen_t client_server_length = sizeof(server_address); // length of the client's address struct

  // DATA TRANSFER VARIABLES
  int number_of_bytes_received, number_of_bytes_read, total_number_of_bytes_read;
  int number_of_bytes_sent;
  int file_size = -1;
  char buffer[MAX_LINE];                                              // reading and writing buffer
  char filename[MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH];
  bool file_read_error = false;
  FILE* requested_file_fd;

  parse_cmd_line_arguments(argc, argv, &udp_port);
  printf("Open for UDP transmissions on port: [%i].\n", udp_port);

  if ((udp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) < 0) {
    perror("Unable to open UDP socket: ");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  set_inet_address(&server_address, AF_INET, INADDR_ANY, udp_port);

  printf("Server is running at address: [%s]:[%i]\n", inet_ntoa(server_address.sin_addr), server_address.sin_port);

  if (bind(udp_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof(server_address)) < 0) {
    perror("Error binding socket to address/port");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  while(TRUE) {
    memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));

    if ((number_of_bytes_received = recvfrom(udp_socket,
                                             buffer,
                                             FILE_REQUEST_SIGNAL_SIZE_BYTES,
                                             RECEIVE_SIGNAL_FLAGS,
                                             (struct sockaddr*) &client_address,
                                             &client_address_length)) < 0) {
      perror("Error receiving signal bytes: ");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (number_of_bytes_received == 0) {
      printf("Received 0 signal bytes. Check client?\n");
    } else {
      printf("Signal received: [%s].\n", buffer);
      strcpy(filename, strchr(buffer, '\n') + 1);
      printf("Requested file: [%s]\n", filename);

      memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
      // Receive client TCP port number.
      if ((number_of_bytes_received = recvfrom(udp_socket,
                                             buffer,
                                             PORT_NUMBER_SIZE_BYTES,
                                             RECEIVE_SIGNAL_FLAGS,
                                             (struct sockaddr*) &client_address,
                                             &client_address_length)) < 0) {
        perror("Error receiving signal bytes: ");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

      if (number_of_bytes_received == 0) {
        printf("Expected port number but nothing was received. Check client?\n");
      } else {
        printf("Received port nummber: [%s].\n", buffer);
        client_address.sin_port = atoi(buffer);

        // Set up TCP socket.
        if ((tcp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) {
          perror("Can't create TCP socket");
          printf("Abandoning File transfer.\n");
          continue;
        }

        if (connect(tcp_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &client_address, client_address_length) < 0) {
          perror("Can't connect to client");
          printf("Abandoning File transfer.\n");
          continue;
        }

        // Open file.
        if((requested_file_fd = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL) {
          perror("Error opening file");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        const FILE* original_fd = requested_file_fd;

        get_file_size(requested_file_fd, &file_size);
        // Read from disk to buffer, then from buffer to client TCP socket.
        printf("The size of the desired file is: [%i].\n", file_size);

        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        number_of_bytes_read = 0, total_number_of_bytes_read = 0;

        while (total_number_of_bytes_read < file_size) {

          // For some reason, requested_file_fd and \
             tcp_socket are altered after fread is called.
          printf("requested_file_fd (before fread): [%x]\n", requested_file_fd);
          printf("tcp_socket (before fread): [%x]\n", tcp_socket);
          int socket = tcp_socket;
          FILE* file = requested_file_fd;
          printf("file (before fread): [%x]\n", file);
          printf("socket (before fread): [%x]\n", socket);
          printf("original_fd (before fread): [%x]\n", original_fd);
          number_of_bytes_read = fread(buffer,
                                      1,
                                      4096,
                                      file);
          // printf("number of bytes read: [%i].\n", number_of_bytes_read);
          printf("requested_file_fd (after fread): [%x]\n", requested_file_fd);
          printf("tcp_socket (after fread): [%x]\n", tcp_socket);
          printf("file (after fread): [%x]\n", file);
          printf("socket (after fread): [%x]\n", socket);
          printf("original_fd (after fread): [%x]\n", original_fd);

          if ((number_of_bytes_read) < 0) {
            perror("Error reading from file");
            file_read_error = true;
            break;
          } else {
            // if ((number_of_bytes_sent = sendto(tcp_socket, buffer, number_of_bytes_read, 0x0, (struct sockaddr*) &client_address, client_address_length)) < 0) {
            if (write(tcp_socket, buffer, number_of_bytes_read) < 0) {
              perror("Error writing file to client");
              break;
            }
            total_number_of_bytes_read += number_of_bytes_read;
          }
        }

        // Close file.
        if (fclose(requested_file_fd) ==  EOF) {
          perror("Error closing file");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // Close TCP socket.
        if ((close(tcp_socket) < 0)) {
          perror("Error closing server tcp socket");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void parse_cmd_line_arguments(int argc, char* argv[], short int* udp_port) {
  char* end_ptr;

  if (argc == 1) {
    *udp_port = DEFAULT_UDP_PORT;
  } else if (argc == 2) {
    *udp_port = strtol(argv[1], &end_ptr, 0);

    if (*end_ptr) {
      printf("Invalid port number provided: %s.\n", argv[1]);
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
  } else {
    printf("Invalid arguments provided.\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
  }
}
```

the helper files:
helper.h:

```
#define TRUE 1
#define MAX_FILE_NAME_LENGTH 255
#define PORT_NUMBER_SIZE_BYTES 5
#define FILE_READ_ELEMENT_SIZE_BYTES 1
#define NUMBER_OF_FILE_READ_ELEMENTS_PER_READ 4096
// #define false 0
// #define true 1


void set_inet_address(struct sockaddr_in* server_address_ptr,
                             const int type,
                             const in_addr_t inet_address,
                             const short int port_number);

void get_file_size(FILE* fd, int*);
```

helper.c:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h> /*  inet (3) funtions         */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "helpers.h"

void set_inet_address(struct sockaddr_in* server_address_ptr,
                             const int inet_family,
                             const in_addr_t inet_address,
                             const short int port_number) {
  memset((char*) server_address_ptr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
  (*server_address_ptr).sin_family = inet_family;
  (*server_address_ptr).sin_addr.s_addr = inet_address;
  (*server_address_ptr).sin_port = port_number;
}

void get_file_size(FILE* fd, int* size) {
  fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
  fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
  *size = ftell(fd);
  fseek(fd, 0, SEEK_SET);
}
```

I expected that the server would simply read the file contents and send them to the client but because tcp_socket and requested_file_fd change the calls to "write" and fclose "fail"

Comment: Buffer overflow! `buffer` is only 1000 bytes in size, but you tell `fread` to store 4096 bytes in it.

Comment: You also make bad assumptions about the order in which you'll receive the UDP packets. You can't count on them being received in the same order as they are sent. Send the entire request in one packet, and get the whole request using one call to `recvfrom`.

Comment: @ikegami yes that's it! thanks! I think I should l have paid more attention to my program, thanks, problem solved.

Comment: Also note that this two-connection approach is problematic. If the client is behind a NAT router, it won't be able to accept the connection without asking the router to forward a port to it.